# Knowing that ${\bf Re}\,c>0$, demonstrate that $|c+\sqrt{c^2-1}|\geq 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> knowing that ${\bf Re}\,c>0$, demonstrate that $|c+\sqrt{c^2-1}|\geq 1$, with equality holding only when $c$ is a real number in the interval $(0,1]$.
>
> **Hint.** First check that ${\bf Re}\,(\bar{c}\sqrt{c^2-1})\geq0 $ for every $c$ under consideration.

\begin{align}
& |c+\sqrt{c^2-1}|\geq 1 \\[10pt]
\Longleftrightarrow \quad & |c+\sqrt{c^2-1}|^2\geq 1^2=1 \\[10pt]
\Longleftrightarrow \quad & (c+\sqrt{c^2-1})(\bar{c}+\sqrt{c^2-1}) \geq 1 \\[10pt]
\Longleftrightarrow \quad & |c|^2+2\operatorname{Re}(c\sqrt{c^2-1})+c^2-1\geq1 \text{?}
\end{align}

This is good, what did I do? How can I use the hint? Thank you very much...

Comment: You got the second factor wrong for one thing, that should be $\,(\bar c + \sqrt{\color{red}{\bar c^2} - 1})\,$.

Comment: @dxiv ok, it is true, what else can you tell ?

Comment: @MichaelHardy 
how could you solve this problem?

Comment: Once you fix that, the last line will have $\,|c^2-1|\,$ (instead of just $\,c^2-1\,$), and $\,|c|^2 + |c^2-1| \ge 1\,$, so this should at least answer the `how can I use the hint` part.